# Renaming similar strings to a single common one and also testing those strings to put into groups

Tags: r, dplyr, stringr

This is my first question I'm asking so I hope I'm being as helpful as I can...

I'm struggling with streamlining some data, particularly strings. I have a dataframe that I pulled with the manufacturer names for a component at work but they're input in many different but similar ways.

To use more commonly known names I'll change to car companies. Such as "Ford Motor Company" , "Ford" , "FoMoCo." "Telsa","Telsa Inc.", "Toyota" "Toyota of Jpn" "Honda", ""Honda Motors (Japan) Co., Ltd." that kind of thing.

I want to change these all to one simplified string like "Ford" " Tesla" etc. Essentially a Find and Replace through the whole Dataframe. I've tried using str_replace_all with some mild success. and it seems I have to use it for every possible outcome, and for some reason it's not working on "Honda Motors (Japan) Co., Ltd.".

Additionally, because I have lots of data weighted to Ford and Tesla, I'd like to Reject anything that ISN'T Ford or Tesla and just call them OTHER. This I have no idea how to approach. Some kind of case statement? I could follow the str_replace_all pattern I guess, but I don't necessarily want to destroy the data thats in the dataframe should I want/need it later. Perhaps I just create a new df with the changes...

I can do this in excel using filters and manually changing it with find replace all, but it's cumbersome, I have to do it manually every week or so when I pull the data and I know isn't the most elegant way to figure it out and doesn't help me in the future.

lets try to reproduce

```
mfg <- c("Ford Motor Company", "Ford Co.", "FoMoCo.", "Tesla", "Tesla Inc.", "Toyota", "Toyota of Jpn", "Honda Motors", "Honda Motors (Japan) Co., Ltd." )

sales <- c(12, 14, 5, 50, 20, 30, 22, 50, 11)

df <- data.frame(mfg, sales)
view(df)

ford_str <- c("Ford Motor Company" = "Ford", "Ford Co." = "Ford", "FoMoCo." = "Ford") 

df$mfg <- str_replace_all(df$mfg,ford_str)
view(df)
```

Generally helps with the strings. but for some reason doesn't work with "Honda Motors (Japan) Co., Ltd.". It will replace all other iterations Honda, but not "Honda Motors (Japan) Co., Ltd.".

I have no clue how to have the Ford, Tesla, Others situation.

Comment: Please make sure the code you are posting is valid and runnable. There are several syntax errors here (missing commas) and variable names that don't match `str_ford` vs `ford_str` and `df` vs `CarSales`). Also you say it doesn't work with Honda but then you didn't include an example that doesn't work. Most likely you want to use `fixed()` to let R know you are not using regular expressions. Something like `str_replace_all(df$mfg,fixed(ford_str))`

Comment: Thanks, and you're right. Sorry. I'm trying to ask this on the fly and wasn't paying attention. 

I'm not sure why it doesn't work with Honda. It works for other vendors. And even other iterations of Honda. Such as the "Honda Motors" becomes just Honda. But when I type unique(df$mfg) I get both Honda and Honda Motors (Japan) Co., Ltd.

Comment: You still have `CarSales` in your code that's not defined. But the reason the Honda one doesn't work is because of the parenthesis. Those are special character for regular expressions. That's why you need to use `fixed()` so those are treated like regular character rather than special ones.

Comment: it seems like the Tesla ones were called "Telsa". I'm guessing this was a typo, so I corrected it. Feel free to roll back if incorrect

Comment: Sorry Mr. Flick I'm editing as I go. Poor form. Thanks for the info on Fixed. Seems like that would make sense since the others are ok.

Answer (score 1):

If you have all your manufacturer-name values in a single named vector you can just do this using a 'lookup'. You can replace missing ones with a default (say "Other"), and further you can use `forcats::fct_other` to re-categorise into "Ford", "Tesla" and "Other".

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble::tribble(
                              ~mfg, ~sales,
              "Ford Motor Company",     12,
                        "Ford Co.",     14,
                         "FoMoCo.",      5,
                           "Telsa",     50,
                      "Telsa Inc.",     20,
                          "Toyota",     30,
                   "Toyota of Jpn",     22,
                    "Honda Motors",     50,
  "Honda Motors (Japan) Co., Ltd.",     11
  )

car_names <-
  c(
    "Ford Motor Company" = "Ford",
    "Ford Co." = "Ford" ,
    "FoMoCo." = "Ford",
    "Telsa" = "Tesla",
    "Telsa Inc." = "Tesla",
    "Toyota" = "Toyota",
    "Toyota of Jpn" = "Toyota",
    "Honda Motors" = "Honda",
    "Honda Motors (Japan) Co., Ltd." = "Honda"
  ) 

df |> 
  mutate(cartype = car_names[mfg]) |> 
  replace_na(list(cartype = "Other")) |> 
  mutate(cartype = fct_other(cartype, keep = c("Ford", "Tesla")))
#> # A tibble: 9 × 3
#>   mfg                            sales cartype
#>   <chr>                          <dbl> <fct>  
#> 1 Ford Motor Company                12 Ford   
#> 2 Ford Co.                          14 Ford   
#> 3 FoMoCo.                            5 Ford   
#> 4 Telsa                             50 Tesla  
#> 5 Telsa Inc.                        20 Tesla  
#> 6 Toyota                            30 Other  
#> 7 Toyota of Jpn                     22 Other  
#> 8 Honda Motors                      50 Other  
#> 9 Honda Motors (Japan) Co., Ltd.    11 Other
```

If you are unsure of all the iterations, you could attempt to merely extract the car names. However this might not catch all ways of expressing the car manufacturer:

```r
df |> 
  mutate(cartype = str_extract(mfg, "Ford|Tesla|Honda|Toyota"))
#> # A tibble: 9 × 3
#>   mfg                            sales cartype
#>   <chr>                          <dbl> <chr>  
#> 1 Ford Motor Company                12 Ford   
#> 2 Ford Co.                          14 Ford   
#> 3 FoMoCo.                            5 <NA>   
#> 4 Tesla                             50 Tesla  
#> 5 Tesla Inc.                        20 Tesla  
#> 6 Toyota                            30 Toyota 
#> 7 Toyota of Jpn                     22 Toyota 
#> 8 Honda Motors                      50 Honda  
#> 9 Honda Motors (Japan) Co., Ltd.    11 Honda
```

Comment: This would work for the limited case of knowing all the mfgs and in theory solves the immediate problem. So thank you. However, if I pull a new query and don't know whats going to show up in the list, how would I do that? If there's 50 more iterations of Ford or Tesla Or Honda, how would one do a "catch all" to replace any variation down to one single name? I've tried looking into wildcards but it doesn't seem to work. But that could easily be my poor capabilities.

What is the df |> command doing? The | is typically used for "or" operations, no? I'm not sure what is happening here?

Comment: I've added a suggestion of another way of doing it by detecting mentions of `"Ford|Tesla|Honda|Toyota"`. There is however a bit of trade-off: you can either tell R "all these strings, including 'FoMoCo', should mean 'Ford'" or "detect if the word Ford" is in the name". If you know that for example 'FoMoCo' exists you could combine the two approaches - extract in one and replace in another. Does that help?

Comment: Thanks Andy. Yes that will be very helpful should I run into situations in the future., Exactly what I was hoping to find. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're just wanting a few categories, it's quite simple to create something which does the job:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% mutate(cat = mfg %>% {case_when(
            str_detect(., "Ford") | . == "FoMoCo." ~ "Ford",
            str_detect(., "Tesla") ~ "Tesla",
            TRUE ~ "Other")})
```

Of course, this would depend on the number of different variations of Ford and Telsa there are, and how often the actual word Ford or Telsa appear in them. If in your actual dataset, the answer is 'sometimes, but not often', then this approach is going to be suboptimal.

Another way which would be easy on the brain (which is underrated, when dealing when messy real world data) is to use a named list:

```
cars <- list("Ford" = c("Ford Motor Company", "Ford Co.", "FoMoCo."),
             "Tesla" = c("Tesla", "Tesla Inc."))
```

Then, in the `case_when()` function above, you can (for example) replace the Ford condition by `. %in% cars$Ford ~ "Ford"`, and so on for Tesla.

Comment: Thanks, Mark, This is what I went with in the end. though using mfg in the mutate statement didnt work I had to do df$mfg (seems the vectors weren't compatible sizes in my Actual data )

This solves the most immediate problem and is pretty easy to understand. Though It won't catch anything that isn't put into the named list. Like you said the "sometimes but not often" scenario. But I think I'll save that for another day. Thanks again.